# HasClass() only working on the second slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, carousel

I'm working with bootstrap's slideshow and I'm really confused as to why the code below doesn't work. Basically, I'm looking to see if a div has a class and if so to make a div fadeIn. Currently it works only on the second slide. On every other slide the div is already there. My guess is because they share the same class however, that does not make sense to me because the condition states only fadeIn if the parent has the class 'active'.

If anyone can explain to me whats happening I would greatly appreciate it.

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

              <!-- Carousel items -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="active item st-cheeseBacon">

                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-7">
                    <div class="st-carouselTitle show">
                     <h3>Bacon &amp; Cheddar Mash</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="item st-chipotle">

                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-7">
                    <div class="st-carouselTitle">
                     <h3 > Chipotle &amp; Cilantro Mash</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="item st-pesto">

                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-7">
                    <div class="st-carouselTitle">
                     <h3>Pesto Mash</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
               ...
              <!-- Carousel nav -->
              <a class="carousel-control left arrowBack" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <div class="arrowBack"></div>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control right arrowNext" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <div class="arrowNext"></div>  
              </a>

              <h3 class="recipeNum">- 1 of 17 -</h3>

            </div>
```

```javascript
$(function(){
 $('.arrowNext').click(function (){
     if($('div.item').hasClass('active')){
         var x = $('div.item').find('.st-carouselTitle').fadeIn(1500);

     } else {
          x = $('.st-carouselTitle').hide();
     }

     console.log(x);
 });
});
```

Comment: Is your console.log(x) not even firing except for the 2nd slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you accomplish your goal through css instead of js?

```
.st-carouselTitle{    
  opacity:0;
}
.active .st-carouselTitle{
 opacity:1;
 transition:opacity 1.5s linear;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c33k47jh/)